# Validate url and extract parameters python

Tags: python, url

I need a library for extracting and validating URL parameters for python.

Something like [this](https://github.com/jessepollak/urlmatch) but with extracting parts of url.

Exactly what rest frameworks do like flask or fast API, but without the whole networking part.

### Example

```
@app.get("/items/{item_id}") # Fastapi
@app.route('/<name>') # Flask
```

Comment: Like the built-in [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.htm) lib ?

Comment: @Kate Something a little bit more declarative imagine parsing sth like that  
``www.stackexchange.com/question-112/anwsers?d=12`` I would need to validate the URL remove the `www`, check if the domain matches, parse the query string, check if the argument is a valid integer, and use regex to extract `112` from URL

Comment: `112` is not a URL parameter per se and requires understanding of the underlying URL rewriting scheme (which can vary from one server to another), then you're better off with a regex but the urllib.parse lib can still be used for a first pass.

Comment: @Kate yes you are right, but for it's something like that is completely valid in flask `@app.route("/post-<name>")`